# MySQL Foreign Keys + which table to put the key on

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I just starting to use Foreign Keys to enforce the contents of certain Columns and want to be sure I'm putting the Key on the correct table.

In a situation with 2 tables that have a one to many relationship.

e.g.: customers (one) and orders (many).

Where I want to ensure a valid customer number is used in an orders column.

I'm I correct in saying the Foreign Key would placed on the orders table.

e.g.: orders (columnX) references customers (columnX)

Comment: Yes, the foreign key is the customer number in the orders table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a foreign key is a referential constraint that says the range of values in a table column(s) is being scoped by another table. Specifically, for your example, you would have a `customer_id` column in your `order` table that would be a ***foreign key*** back to the `customer` table, meaning that the in all cases you need a valid customer id in order to insert a record in the order table.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the primary key (typically a customer id) on the *one* table (customers) should be linked as a foreign key on the *many* table (orders) in a one-to-many relationship. Each order can belong to only one customer, but a customer can place many orders.